# PUT request with json Body and multipart files array

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, postman

I have a rest java webservice using a PUT method for updating an employee.

The web service should take a list of files and a json containig the infos to be updated.

The method has the following signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{employeeId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = 
 MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> updateEmployee(
         @RequestPart EmployeeUserUpdateDto employeeDto,
         @PathVariable("employeeId") int employeeId,
         @RequestPart MultipartFile[] uploadedFiles, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

When i test this request with postman like follows it says that my json is not present:

[image]

PS : I have a similar post request for adding an employee, working just fine with the same configuration , the sole diffrence between the 2 requests is the pathvariable and PUT  not POST

Answer (score 0):

add over method : @ResponseBody

Comment: nope response body and multipart form data are not friends ;)

Comment: If you are returning ResponseEntity, there is no need to add @ResponseBody

Answer (score 0):

You can get multipart request in dto wrapper like this:

```
@PutMapping("/upload-poc")
  ResponseEntity<?> uploadFileWithData(@ModelAttribute TestModel model){
    log.info("File Exist: {}",model.getImage().get(0).getOriginalFilename());
    log.info("Data: {}", model);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class TestModel{
  private List<MultipartFile> images;

  //@NotNull(message = "Name must be provided")
  @Size(min = 2, max = 6)
  private String name;

  private Long id;
}
```

I am uploading 3 files in one request.

Here is the post man request sample:

[image]

Comment: can u share how are u testing this ? i mean inside json how are u adding images ?

Comment: @kmarakrout screen shot added. Let me know if I can help you further.

Comment: i'm working on a backend app that will have an angular front, im afraid this will be a problem with the front guys and i can't test now with a form so i want to know is this going to accept an uploaded file from a form ?

Comment: also can i change modelAttribute by responsebody ?

Comment: @kmarakrout In angular it can be easily handled without creating form. So no need to worry about this. You can go with this approach. And ResponseBody is class level annotation so no need to change the modelAttribute. You can simply add the ResponseBody on your method without removing modelAttribute. Infact in my code sample PostMapping and RestController already defined the responsebody

Comment: after testing i realised that you are entring the attributes each at a time. in my case i have a biiig dto containing tons of attributes so i need to give the web service a json !

Comment: This is impossible to send JSON as well as form data with the request because Http can only have one request type. Rather you can pass the JSON string into the parameter. But this is not the proper way just workaround.